# Playing audio from a Python file with PyAudio in HTML

Tags: python, html, pyaudio

I'm trying to get my HTML page do read the Python file and play a .wav file when I use the 'onclick' operation. I'm familiar that this works with JavaScript functions but I don't know about Python, since I tried to do the same thing but it did not work. Here's the code:

**sound.html**

```
    <head>
        <title>Play Music</title>
        <style>
            .button {
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 16px 32px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 4px 2px;
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .button1 {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                border: 2px solid green
            }
            .button1:hover {
                background-color: green;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Sound Test</p>
        <script type="text/python" src="audio.py"></script>
        <button class="button button1" onclick="play('drumbit.wav')">Sound</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**audio.py**

```
import cherrypy
import pyaudio
import wave
from array import array
from struct import pack

#class Audio(object):
    #@cherrypy.expose
def play(file):
    CHUNK = 1024

    wf = wave.open(file, 'rb')

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                        channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                        rate=wf.getframerate(),
                        output=True)

    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    while len(data) > 0:
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    p.terminate()
    return open("sound.html")
#play("drumbit.wav")
```

Thanks!

Comment: HTML cannot read python code. You need first bring audio file from server to client than play it using audio tag of html

Comment: Is there any way to make a jscript function to run a python code, and from that I'd run the jscript code from html? I don't get how I'll do the server-client connection for the audio